# How can I access redux states inside normal functions, which are not react Components?

Tags: react-native, redux

I have a js file containing different functions, I need to access updated redux state in some of those functions, but I don't know how can I get redux states.

I tried to create a file with this code and named it reduxStore.js:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducers from './../reducers';

const storeBox = createStore(reducers);

export default storeBox;
```

and in my target js file I tried to import it like this:

```
import storeBox from './reduxStore';
```

and then I tried to access the states inside my function :

```
export function PlaySounds(type, state, soundSetting = null) {
    let states = storeBox.getState();
    console.log('ssss', states)
    if (states.settingPage.music) {
        switch (type) {
            case 'gamemusic':
                if (state == true) {
                    gameSound.play().setNumberOfLoops(-1);
                    //sound.setNumberOfLoops(-1);
                } else {
                    //console.log('stopped Trigger')
                    gameSound.setCurrentTime(0).stop();
                }
                break;
            case 'singlemode':
                if (state == true) {
                    singlemode.play().setNumberOfLoops(-1);
                } else {
                    singlemode.setCurrentTime(0).stop();
                }
                break;
            case 'singlemodeFast':
                if (state == true) {
                    singlemodeFast.play().setNumberOfLoops(-1);
                } else {
                    singlemodeFast.setCurrentTime(0).stop();
                }
                break;
            case 'singlemodeShock':
                if (state == true) {
                    singlemodeShock.play(() => {
                        singlemode.play().setNumberOfLoops(-1);
                    });
                    //sound.setNumberOfLoops(-1);
                } else {
                    singlemodeShock.stop();
                }
                break;
            case 'onlinemode':
                if (state == true) {
                    onlinemode.play().setNumberOfLoops(-1);
                    //sound.setNumberOfLoops(-1);
                } else {
                    onlinemode.setCurrentTime(0).stop();
                }
                break;
            case 'buttonClick':
                buttonClick.play();
                break;
            case 'winner':
                winnerSound.play();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

But the problem is it will return the initial state all the time and not the updated redux states. so it's useless.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You are not subscribed to the store. You need to connect to the store, if you want to see the changes. Try doing

`storeBox.subscribe(PlaySounds)` after the function.

Comment: I tried it but didn't work. still getting initial states

Comment: you wrote the subscribe outside the function right?

Comment: hmm. instead of exporting it like that, try `export default PlaySounds;` after subscribing.